# PyQT listview or not list view?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Ok rewrite :

I want to display 10 folders( I know how to do this part). I want to display them in 1 window(well widget not window I want both of the windows to be in 1 window...). Then select ones I want and move them to window 2 for further edition... Is listview the right approach?

#### OLD stuff below - ignore

Right so what I want to create is a listviewer and list selection - sort off. 
So far I have a way of selecting folder on HDD and displaying its content in listview -call it LS_A. Now the next step was to create second empty listview- LS_B.

Then the idea was to shift/ctrl select items on LS_A and add them to LS_B (or delete them from LS_B by selecting them there bla bla bla) In any case I cant select more than 1 object from LS_A and since I cant do that I didn't try to make the movement action from LS_A to LS_B yet so any advice would be great. Is the listview right approach or I need other ? If some1 has example code - great if no just point me to the right wording that I need to use because I have no idea what I'm googling for :( Bottom line is I want to get my selection in to LS_B and then use it to execute some scripts which should be easy part and on python side... the QT...

Thanks, bye.

Comment: This was an extremely confusing piece. I suggest a thorough rewrite.

Comment: Got it solvedm ore or less. :)

Comment: Than add your answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer please.